# Javascript help with retrieving data from list SP2010

Tags: list, javascript, calculated-column

I would like to retrieve data from a list that has 2 columns but 4 fields.

Ex. I need the calculation from monthly & yearly cost from group 1 and calculations for monthly cost & yearly cost based on group 2.

I think some JavaScript should do the trick just don’t know where to start.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy done with JavaScript:

Retrieve Function will be something like this:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

function retrieveListItems() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('ListName');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><</Query></View>');
    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

    var listItemInfo = '';

    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        var group1Calculation=0;
        var group2Calculation=0;
        if(oListItem.get_item('groupName')=="Group1")
        {
            group1Calculation += parseInt(oListItem.get_item('monthly')) + parseint(oListItem.get_item('monthly'));
        }

        if(oListItem.get_item('groupName')=="Group2")
        {
            group2Calculation += parseInt(oListItem.get_item('monthly')) + parseint(oListItem.get_item('monthly'));
        }

    }

    alert(group1Calculation.toString());
    alert(group2Calculation.toString());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```